# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - AddAuthentication and DefaultScheme

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to upgrade an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application to 2.0.  The application needs two both the basic authentication and JWT one.  I have got code which looks something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                .AddBasic(BasicScheme, _ => { })
                .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {...}
```

My problem is that I can't seem to get both of them to work at the same time!  Whichever one I set as the DefaultScheme is the only one that works and the other one breaks and returns a HTTP 401.

Any ideas how can I get both of them to work?

Answer (score 4):

Just managed to get this to work... this link helped: https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2

The important bit is here:

> When we use the Authorize attribute, it actually binds to the first authentication system by default. The trick is to change the attribute to specify which auth to use:

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove option from AddAuthotization method:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddBasic(BasicScheme, _ => { })
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {...}
```

Then modify your Configure() method Startup.cs adding the following Use instructions:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // Write some code that determines the scheme based on the incoming request
            string scheme = GetSchemeForRequest(context);
            var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                context.User = result.Principal;

            }
            await next();
        });
```

Now in the GetSchemeForRequest method you can determine which scheme you should use.
I found the answer [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1469#issuecomment-334982498) and applied on my code. It works!

Answer (score 3):

Adding this line of code to Startup.cs worked for me

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie("LoggedIn");
```